# 2 SSD, 1 HDD, why is second SSD much slower when copying data HDD -> SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, performance

For nearly 2 years I've been using 250GB SSD for system (drive C), and 500GB HDD for storage (drive D).

Today I added a second SSD (drive E, 1TB) to my PC, so I don't have to keep moving games between HDD and system SSD. I noticed that when moving a whole game folder stored on my HDD, speed for my new SSD is 60-70 MB/s, while for my old SSD it's 130-140 MB/s.

Manufacturer's disk utility program shows that both SSDs have roughly the same write speed (system drive has slighty faster read speed). So why is the difference so big?

AHCI, Trim, page file, prefetch etc. are all set as they should be. Could it be related to order how the disks are connected to the motherboard (Asrock 880G Extreme3), or maybe something in BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some digging I have found my answer.

My old SSD has 256MB of cache memory, while the other one has no cache at all. While that shouldn't affect games' performance, it affects speed during heavy file transfer.

I only wonder why I had to find that info on some third party site. Since manufacturer doesn't mention cache at all in specifications of both disks, I simply assumed none of them has it.